# Error using ~= Matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab, image-processing, dcom

I'm using the following code of "Computed tomography-based volumetric tool for standardized measurement of the maxillary sinus" article to measure the volume of the maxillary sinus in DCOM images:

```
% Read images
clear all
close all

[filename, pathname] = uigetfile('*','Select CT exam (all slices)','MultiSelect','on');
num= length(filename);
bbbb=1;


step=input('Step of image reading: \')


for aaaa = 1:step:num
    xinfo=dicominfo([pathname,char(filename(aaaa))]);
    pxsp=cat(2,xinfo.PixelSpacing);
    x=dicomread([pathname,char(filename(aaaa))])+cat(2,xinfo.RescaleIntercept);
    k=x;
    k = im2bw(k,0.49);
    k = imfill(k,'holes');
    cc = bwconncomp(k);
    stats = regionprops(cc,'Area');
    A = [stats.Area];
    [~,biggest] = max(A);
    k(labelmatrix(cc)~=biggest) = 0;
    x(k~=1)=-2000;     
    masccranio(:,:,bbbb)=k;
    cranio(:,:,bbbb)=x;
    cranio_full(:,:,bbbb)=x;
    bbbb=bbbb+1;
    end
```

at the first, we don't have any idea about the reading step input at the beginning, please help on that if you can. Our second problem is when we run the code we get the following error:

```
Error using  ~= 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in Quant (line 32)
    k(labelmatrix(cc)~=biggest) = 0;
```

I'm using Matlab 2019b and as I know this code is for 2013. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `dbstop if error` in MATLAB before you run the code. MATLAB will stop right after the error and open your code in the debugger, where you can see the value of each of the variables and so on. There you can figure out what `labelmatrix(cc)` and `biggest` are, and why their dimensions are not the same.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I did that but unfortunately labelmatrix(cc) and biggest are not same

Comment: Of course, the error message is telling you that. But that is your tool to figure out *why* they are the sizes they are, and what changes you need to make to get the code to work.

Answer (score 0):

I expect you want `biggest` to represent the biggest value of all region areas in this line:

```
k(labelmatrix(cc)~=biggest) = 0;
```

In that case, your problem is likely that `A` is not a vector, and therefore `biggest` is not a scalar. This causes the operation to fail as the `~=` operator only works on matrices of the same size or with scalars.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If my assumption is correct, you should be able to get a scalar for `biggest` like this:
`[~,biggest] = max(A(:));`
This will convert the matrix A to a vector. Note this will only work if A is matrix. If A is not a matrix, you will have to convert it to a matrix first.